# What is a "medium duty" wood clamp?

Tags: clamps

[Here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=medium%20duty%20clamp) is a web search for "medium duty clamp."

What is "medium duty" versus "heavy duty"?  Is there an official definition?

Comment: Hi, welcome to woodworking. There's no technical or official definition of medium or heavy, at least not one that's used across makers. It's just a rough guide to how much you can crank down the handle before the clamp bends or breaks LOL (Joking aside I mean this literally, lighter-duty clamps often bend in use if they're tightened a bit too much.)

Comment: Thanks. What does "light duty", "medium duty", "heavy duty" mean to an experienced woodworker?

Comment: Individual mileage varies. You'll get slightly different opinions on this from person to person, based on what they've used, what their requirements are — if you use hide glue almost exclusively your definition of "heavy clamping" could be very different to someone using PVA glues where you must clamp very hard to get strong joints. I also think how physically strong a person is will factor into this (particularly hand strength).

Comment: I have clamps in all three categories, but it's important to note that none of them were sold described as light-, medium- or heavy-duty. Also the dividing line between the classes is definitely not sharply defined. I have big F-clamps that you'd assume were heavy-duty because of their size and beefiness, but they can still bend if cranked up to 11, so I'd have to class them medium-duty (even though they're *way* stronger than the med-sized ones). All my G-clamps except for the smallest I would class as heavy duty. G-clamps in general are usually the strongest clamps in any workshop.

Comment: Thanks! You should add some of this text to an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure TBH that this is a suitable Q for here so I'm reluctant to add a formal Answer. I voted to close based on my reservations; I think this is too open to manufacturer definition (varied, without being specified) or individual opinion/interpretation (equally varied and unspecified LOL).

Comment: I feel like "there's no defined standard" is a fine answer! Why close a question on a beta stackexchange? You want more traffic, not less.

Comment: Because, standards? :-) Edit: seriously while I do mean that you deserve a better answer than this and to be perfectly frank I suspect this SE won't move out of beta; I don't think the format is a good fit for woodworking-related questions.

Comment: "Official" according to whom? There aren't really any governing bodies or standards organizations in woodworking. Heck, we can't even agree on what a planer is.

Comment: My question was "Is there an official definition?" For some reason, you're answering that with a question. But, I think your answer is, "No, there is not an official definition." I don't understand why everyone's getting so hung up on some imprecision. I learned a lot from this exchange, and I'm not at all bothered that it's not 100% precise.

Comment: @dfrankow The word *official* in this context requires some stated or implied governing body. If you'd asked what the official distance from home plate to first base is, we could reasonably assume that you're asking about  baseball or softball, and we could give you the rules according to the MLB (90 ft) or the ISF (60 ft). No such body exists for the sport of woodworking. Comments here are for seeking clarification, and I asked you for more info because you seem to be asking for a precise definition from a governing body where neither exist.

Comment: Answer accepted! You were correct, I was asking about official. Sounds like there is no official, and that's fine.

Comment: Actually, "medium-duty", "heavy-duty", etc. are marketing terms. They have little to do with the item or tool being sold, but as a rule of thumb the difference is, generally, a 25-40% increase in price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is "medium duty" versus "heavy duty"? Is there an official definition?

There's no specific definition of "medium duty" or "heavy duty" as those terms pertain to woodworking tools, and the same is probably true in most other contexts. The terms are essentially marketing terms that manufacturers use to suggest the intended use of a product or to differentiate similar products within their own product line. Moreover, the meanings may vary significantly depending on the specific products or the context in which they're described.

It's generally understood that "medium duty" suggests more toughness and durability than "light duty," but less than "heavy duty," even if none of those terms are precisely defined. Think of these meanings in terms of condiments: when you order a sandwich at a delicatessen and the person behind the counter asks if you want mayonnaise, you might say "heavy mayo, please" or perhaps "medium mayo" or "light mayo," and even though they're not measuring the mayo and if asked you probably couldn't even say just how many grams of mayonnaise are indicated by "medium mayo," everybody still has a pretty good idea of what you mean.

There's no authority or governing body that controls, defines, designates, or authorizes the use of those terms for clamps or other tools. Consider them as advisory if they help, or ignore them entirely and evaluate the products in question yourself.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that what one manufacturer considers "medium-duty" another may consider "heavy-duty", while a 3rd scoffs and calls it "light-duty". These are nothing but marketing terms.